# How to archive a folder as tar.bz2 file and upload to universal packages from Azure Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

The following code is for archive, but how to upload the archived tar.bz2 to a universal packages from Azure Artifacts

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    #rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)' 
    #includeRootFolder: true 
    #archiveType: 'tar' 
    #tarCompression: 'bz2' 
    #archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(fileName)_$(Build.BuildId).tar.bz2' 
    #replaceExistingArchive: true 
    #verbose: # Optional
    #quiet: # Optional
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To publish a Universal Package to your feed, add the following snippet to your azure-pipelines.yml file.

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: Universal Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    vstsFeedPublish: '<projectName>/<feedName>'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: '<Package name>'
    versionOption: custom
    versionPublish: '<Package version>'
    packagePublishDescription: '<Package description>'
```

By default, the Universal Packages task will publish all files in`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. To prepare your Universal Package for publishing, either configure preceding tasks to place output files in that directory, or use the [Copy Files utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops) task to assemble the files that you want to publish.

For details ,please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).